# How can I delete a file in a cron job?

Tags: cron

A custom module is creating a file in `public://` folder, that should reside there only temporary. How can I delete this temporary file in a cron job?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Also in drupal, we can delete a file on a cron job via setting the file status=0.

After 6 hours the cron job will delete the files whose status is zero.

```
     $filename = "myfile.pdf";
     $tmp_file = file_save_data('', 'public://' . $filename);
     $tmp_file->status = 0; // will automatically delete
     $tmp_file->save();
```

Answer (score 2):

Write a function in a custom module:

```
/**
* Implements hook_cron().
*/
mymodule_cron() {
  // Get the file id somehow, make this more generic, perhaps use file_scan_directory()?
  $uri = 'public://temporary/myfile.pdf';
  $files = \Drupal::entityTypeManager()
    ->getStorage('file')
    ->loadByProperties(['uri' => $uri]);
  if (count($files)) {
    foreach ($files as $item) {
      file_delete($item->id());
    }
  }
}
```